# How to access json string

Tags: php, json

I have parsed json , and i would get the `screen_name` variable, how to do it?

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [created_at] => Sat Nov 04 15:56:21 +0000 2017 
        [id] => 926840548538966017 
        [id_str] => 926840548538966017 
        [text] => I liked a @YouTube video MAX BASS Music Mix 2017 Extreme Bass Test Music for Car 
        [truncated] => 
        [entities] => stdClass Object ( 
            [hashtags] => Array ( ) 
            [symbols] => Array ( ) 
            [user_mentions] => Array ( 
                [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                [screen_name] => YouTube 
                [name] => YouTube 
                [id] => 10228272 
                [id_str] => 10228272 
                [indices] => Array ( 
                    [0] => 10 
                    [1] => 18 
                ) 
            ) 
        ) 
        [urls] => Array ( 
            [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                [url] =>  
                [expanded_url] =>  
                [display_url] => youtu.be/VkLkUOn3BIw?a 
                [indices] => Array ( 
                    [0] => 25 
                    [1] => 48 
                ) 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
    [metadata] => stdClass Object ( 
        [iso_language_code] => en 
        [result_type] => recent 
    ) 
    [source] => Google 
    [in_reply_to_status_id] => 
    [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => 
    [in_reply_to_user_id] => 
    [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 
    [in_reply_to_screen_name] => 
    [user] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 77408161 
        [id_str] => 77408161 
        [name] => Dredluv Jones 
        [screen_name] => Gingerdred 
        [location] => Saint Louis, MO 
        [description] => NANBF/INBF Sponsor: P4P Muscle Promo: Angell15 Fitness.Music.InkLife.Foodie. Dogs.BigTrucks.Autobots.UFC/MMA Dancing & a dork! STL! 
        [url] =>  
        [entities] => stdClass Object ( 
            [url] => stdClass Object ( 
                [urls] => Array ( 
                    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                        [url] =>  
                        [display_url] => instagram.com/dredluvjones 
                        [indices] => Array ( 
                            [0] => 0 
                            [1] => 23 
                        ) 
                    ) 
                ) 
            ) 
            [description] => stdClass Object ( 
                [urls] => Array ( 
                    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                        [url] => 
                        [expanded_url] => 
                        [display_url] => FACEBOOK.COM/ROCKENKITCHEN 
                        [indices] => Array ( 
                            [0] => 132 
                            [1] => 155 
                        ) 
                    ) 
                ) 
            ) 
        ) 
        [protected] => 
        [followers_count] => 1080 
        [friends_count] => 2586 
        [listed_count] => 112 
        [created_at] => Sat Sep 26 05:46:03 +0000 2009 
        [favourites_count] => 3639 
        [utc_offset] => -18000 
        [time_zone] => Central Time (US & Canada) 
        [geo_enabled] => 1 
        [verified] => 
        [statuses_count] => 16318 
        [lang] => en 
        [contributors_enabled] => 
        [is_translator] => 
        [is_translation_enabled] => 
        [profile_background_color] => 000000 
        [profile_background_image_url] =>  
        [profile_background_image_url_https] =>  
        [profile_background_tile] => 
        [profile_image_url] =>  
        [profile_image_url_https] =>  
        [profile_banner_url] =>  
        [profile_link_color] => 96B50D 
        [profile_sidebar_border_color] => 000000 
        [profile_sidebar_fill_color] => 000000 
        [profile_text_color] => 000000 
        [profile_use_background_image] => 
        [has_extended_profile] => 1 
        [default_profile] => 
        [default_profile_image] => 
        [following] => 
        [follow_request_sent] => 
        [notifications] => 
        [translator_type] => none 
    ) 
    [geo] => 
    [coordinates] => 
    [place] => 
    [contributors] => 
    [is_quote_status] => 
    [retweet_count] => 0 
    [favorite_count] => 0 
    [favorited] => 
    [retweeted] => 
    [possibly_sensitive] => 
    [lang] => en 
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you post the original string, it is hard to read what level the `screen_name` is under in that long line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 `screen_name` in the json:

```
yourParsedJson[0]->entities->user_mentions['screen_name']
yourParsedJson[0]->user->screen_name
```